# Consecutive numbered values to records in Ruby on Rails according to sort by created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For a project my company is involved in, I need to forward some data according to their ***consecutive*** numbering according to their creation date(time). Some data is already stored.

The only way I found up to now is to set a similar value as the `id` column for a model in Ruby on Rails. These values are consecutive starting from 1 (to `n`, with `n` being the number of records in the table), according to the values of another column.
I don't want to override the default `id` column, of course.

I just came up with the following code:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
...
def id_2
  User.all.order(:created_at).index(self) + 1
end
```

But I sense that there can be some better way to this approach, even database-oriented.

Is there a more efficient implementation for this, instead of calling the whole contents of the table, as per the code?

Comment: So to clarify, for example, if the record was the *third to be created* then `user.id_2 == 3`?

Comment: Why do you need this? What is the real problem you're trying to solve? I suspect this could be an XY question.

Comment: If I understand correctly, a more efficient query would be: `User.where('created_at <= ?', created_at).count`. However, this is *not reliable* since there is no guarantee that the `created_at` values are unique - therefore the `id_2` may not be well-defined.

Comment: @TomLord yes, I updated the question accordingly. I agree with the non-reliability of your previous comment, but I believe there must be a more straightforward way.

Comment: My way *is* a little more straightforward, since the query is being performed in pure SQL rather than loading all records into memory, then querying in ruby. This will trigger a command like: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE (created_at <= '......')`. But again, I ask: Why are you doing this? What problem are you trying to solve? Are you asking the wrong question?

Comment: **Maybe** you could add a new database column (as suggested below), but if the column values being compared against can *change*, then this will do more harm than good. I'd need more information to provide any more of an answer.

Comment: @TomLord updated question again. I have to send some data in a table with their consecutive numbering. I just wanted to ask about a possible more efficient approach to this, otherwise I just leave the code as it is.

Comment: Your update still doesn't really explain what you're trying to do. Loop through *all* records, in order of `created_at`, and forward that data? Lookup specific records, according to their "`created_at`-position"? Doesn't the `id` column *pretty much* provide this information already, or is the issue that some records have been deleted?

Comment: @TomLord I would use the `id` column, but the value must be consecutive, also when records are deleted. Records are looked up (i.e. to retrieve a subset of them)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163807/discussion-between-simon-and-tom-lord).

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports it, you probably should simply set you column to auto_increment

```
add_column :table_name, :id_2, :integer, auto_increment: true
```

Comment: What if I delete records? Does `auto_increment` imply that the indexes are recalculated after that, in order to match the `1..n` condition?

Comment: I misundertood what you wanted. No, it would not be recalculated